# How to add the "é" in a Font with the resource Editor?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

In the resource Editor I created a Font , and I checked the "Create Bitmap" checkbox. The problem is that the "é" is not included in the "Charset". So how to include the "é" ?

PS : What does "anti-aliasing" mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows:
have you tried pressing alt+0233 ?

Mac:
Have you tried pressing option + e then e?

Comment: Thank you very much the alt+0233 works very well. You all are good !